# How to analyze several tables in php without MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

We are working on a stock market analysis website based on php, which reads the history of price for each symbol (by data scraping) and uses that history data (in form of tables) to analyse the stock chart based on mathematical calculation.

Each symbol is located on a specific URL which is scraped by php dynamically:

```
date        price
20190601    12.2
20190602    12.1
```

- Each URL has a table of two columns of 'date' and 'Price' ,
- Each URL has a table of 100-1000 rows of data.

> **The problem is**: We are scraping data for 900 symbols and we need to
>   collect data and analyze them, but should I store the data in MySQL
>   and update them every day (by adding a new row) or can I collect data
>   and analyze them in php in real time ?

if I have to store data in MySQL, then there should be 900 tables (one for each symbol) ?
Please guide me what would be best approach to this matter.

Thank you guys, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would there need to be 900 tables? Just have one table and add the symbol as the last column in the table, so you can tell which data belongs to which symbol. How much data is there for each symbol? If it's a lot, PHP could conceivably run out of memory if you try to load it all at once. Also, SQL is extremely quick and efficient and certain kinds of query and analysis, so depending what calculations you want to do, that could be a big advantage

Comment: Dear ADyson

thanks for prompt response. it helps a lot,

if we want to assume one table only:

there is 900 symbol (as 900 cols) and 4 price for each date (open, high, low and close) for each symbol which is :
 900*4 = 3600 prices for one day.


then there is a almost 5 years history for each symbol. (250 working days for each year).


so the table shall be 3600 cols and 1250 rows if it is to be only one table. 


any idea ?

Comment: No that would be a poor design. It would be inflexible and hard to query effectively. A more conventional design would be one where you would have 4 columns - date, price, type (i.e. high/low/open/close) and symbol. Then you have one row for each combination of those factors.